# confusion in JSON object singletone behavior?

Tags: javascript, json

Am new to client side application development, need some clarity on below mentioned issue.

I have one object  `var obj1={'name':'Sachin'}`

I assign that object to `obj2`

```
var obj2=obj1.
```

Now my `obj2` and `obj1` objects both are same

Now by using `obj2` I change the name property value like

```
obj2.name="Dravid";
```

Now my `obj1` and `obj2`  both name property values turned to be 'Dravid' because of 'sigletone' behavior of JSON object? is it correct?

Now my question is:

if I made my `obj1` is empty like

```
   obj1={}
```

then why my `obj2` is not turned to be empty ?

still it show `obj2={'name':'Dravid'}`

What is the reason behind that ?

Could please help me on this.

thanks in advance...

---

Comment: Note, `JSON` is a string, not a JavaScript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that when you make the first assignment, `obj1` and then assign `obj1` to `obj2`, you are copying a shared reference to the same position in memory. Then when you assign the empty `{ }` to `obj1`, you are creating a new object in memory, replacing the other reference. At that point `obj1` and `obj2` have different references

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript Objects are passed as references. So obj1 and obj2 are referencing the same object when you make changes you only change one object referenced by 2 variables. If you assign obj1 to another object, it has no affect on the reference on obj2.